# Reading multiple lines of multiple numbers(the amount of numbers are not specified) in C

Tags: c, linux

I need to make a program that takes two lines of input, each one composed of an unspecified amount of numbers, and store each one in a separate vector(int*).

It's not allowed to use a string to store the input and then convert it to int.

It has to work in a linux enviroment, actually I've solved it for Windows with the following code:

```
int t,s1=0,s2=0;
char tx;
int* a=(int*)malloc(0);
int* b=(int*)malloc(0);
scanf("%i%c",&t,&tx);
while(tx!='\n')
{
    a=(int*)realloc(a,sizeof(int)*(s1+1));
    a[s1++]=t;
    scanf("%i%c",&t,&tx);
}
a=(int*)realloc(a,sizeof(int)*(s1+1));
a[s1++]=t;
scanf("%i%c",&t,&tx);
while(tx!='\n')
{
    b=(int*)realloc(b,sizeof(int)*(s2+1));
    b[s2++]=t;
    scanf("%i%c",&t,&tx);
}
b=(int*)realloc(b,sizeof(int)*(s2+1));
b[s2++]=t;
```

I've tested it on linux and, at least for me, It doesn't work.

I would really appreciate your help, thank you very much!

Comment: There is no need to cast void-pointers in C, nor is it recommended in any way. Just remove those useless casts.

Comment: "*It doesn't work.*" is the more or less worth trouble report one can give. Please be more specific: What do you expect? What do you get?

Comment: "vector(int*)" I feel like this might be a C++ question...

Comment: Note that code like `old_ptr = realloc(old_ptr, new_size);` will leak the memory allocated if the reallocation fails and returns a null pointer.  To avoid that, you should always use: `new_ptr = realloc(old_ptr, new_size); if (new_ptr != 0) { old_ptr = new_ptr; old_size = new_size; } else { …report out-of-memory error… }` or something similar.  Also, incrementing the size allocated by one each time is not good; it can lead to quadratic behaviour.  The usual rule of thumb is to double the amount of space allocated.  It requires an extra variable to keep track of allocated vs used space.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "It doesn't work" and not posting input used and outputs seen makes it insufficient to replicate the problem.

Comment: the posted code does not compile. (missing `#include` statements, missing function definitions, like `int main( void ) { ... } ) voting to close as off topic as does not follow the rules for 'run time' questions.

Answer (score 3):

I tried your program on linux and for me, it worked. I used the following input file:

```
1 2 3
4 5
```

I ran it in gdb and after the final statement, the debugger gave the following values:

```
(gdb) print s1
$4 = 3
(gdb) print s2
$5 = 2
(gdb) print a[0]
$6 = 1
(gdb) print a[1]
$7 = 2
(gdb) print a[2]
$8 = 3
(gdb) print b[0]
$9 = 4
(gdb) print b[1]
$10 = 5
(gdb)
```

But the code probably will fail, if there are trailing blanks in the input data.

You also do not check the return value of scanf(), so it might enter an endless loop, if scanf() fails, e.g. due to early EOF.

You might also encounter problems, if you feed your program input data from a file using windows line endings (\r\n).

I also would advice to use a `do {} while (tx!='\n')` loop, as it eliminates duplicate code.